# Generate parser from EBNF

Tags: parsing, haskell, autocomplete, parsec

I want to create tools make developer work more easy (autocomplete, linting, refactoring etc).

The first step would be to create a tool that can take grammar in some form (I'm thinking about EBNF) and create parser for it.
The most pleasant option is to use Parsec, but I've as it is top-down parser wouldn't it be less performant then bottom up one?
Are there bottom-up parser generators for Haskell that can be created easily from BNF?

Also how parse only part of file that changes as user changes the sources?

```
type Grammar = String
type Label = String

data ParseTree a = Node
    { label :: Label
      start :: Integer
    , childrens :: [ParseTree]
    } | Leaf {value :: a} deriving Show

mkParser :: Grammar -> Parser ParseTree
mkParser = undefined
```

From ParseTree various data can be taken and stored persistently like function definition places, usages etc.
Next step is type inference, but for that I believe someone should define for each language what are function and data types definitions.

After that I think the algorithm would be language independent.

And from that there would be able to give suggestions and autocompletion and linting.

So is my train  of thought is going into right direction? And what are the answers to a more concrete questions in the start?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Happy](https://www.haskell.org/happy/). It is an amazing parser generator. Not only does it support all of the standard parser generator features, but it is very well integrated with Haskell: it supports parametrized productions, type signatures (even with constraints), ADT tokens, and custom underlying parsing monad. It expects BNF (although with parametrized productions, you can make your own extended BNF).

Comment: Seems like with bnf converter I can have almost what I want. I actually thought about expressing parse tree as tree with string labels and generating parser in runtime instead of compile time, but this also may work.